# How do I make a form auto select if navigated to from specific link

Tags: forms, post, hyperlink

Sorry. I'm not exactly sure how to sum up what I'm looking for so I'll just explain the situation.

I have a page with 2 links(A & B), both going to the same form.

Whats the easiest way to have:

if form is navigated to from link A than select this box and put this value in text field.

if form is navigated to from link B than select a different box and put a different value in text field.

If someone could just point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

////edit - heres my code/////

The links on the html page:

```
<a href="/donation_form.php" name="A" id="A" target="_blank">
<a href="/donation_form.php" name="B" id="B" target="_blank">
```

The code for the php form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="preferred_referral" value="Preferred" > Preferred <br>             
<input type="checkbox" name="prestige_referral" value="Prestige" > Prestige <br>

<?
$form->addElement('text','amount_fees','Total Amount: $');
?>
```

Comment: if you could post some code that would help us help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The beat approach would be to pass a parameter when you navigate to your form page, and retrieve and act upon it.
For instance, pageA would point to form.html?fromPage=A and pageB to form.html?fromPage=B
Then modify the form based on the fromPage parameter. This can be done server side, or client side with JavaScript for instance.